# To solve the delete error in realm mongo db atlas

Tags: mongodb, react-native, error-handling, realm, delete-file

I created a todo app using Realm and react native there are two buttons in it one is complete and another one deletes the complete button works. but when I click the delete it will throw this error .

ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: Accessing object of type Task which has been invalidated or deleted

I want to solve my problem

```
  const deleteTask = async (taskId) => {
    if (user && email) {
      const realmInstance = await realm(email);
      realmInstance.write(() => {
        const task = realmInstance.objectForPrimaryKey('Task', taskId);
        if (task) {
          try {
            realmInstance.delete(task);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error while deleting task:', error);
          }
        } else {
          console.error('Task not found in the realm.');
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: You code works for me so I would say the issue lies outside of that code. I suggest some further troubleshooting may help by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. It's possible the add function is not working properly or perhaps it's referencing a different realm entirely.